# WebSphere MQ Receiver Channel Paused

Tags: ibm-mq

I think I tried to start a channel that is already running or whatever. Whenever I start the sender channel, the receiver channel goes to a PAUSED state. [I looked it up](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21080140) and found something about AdoptNewMCA configuration, not sure how to set it at the queue manager level. How do I fix this smoothly. Merely stopping and restarting the channels does not do it.

Error log says:

```
/02/2012 12:38:41 PM - Process(19161.269) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host() Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.1.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST2)

AMQ9514: Channel 'QM_TEST1.TO.QM_TEST2' is in use.

EXPLANATION: The requested operation failed because channel
''QM_TEST1.TO.QM_TEST2' is currently active. ACTION: Either end the channel
manually, or wait for it to close, and retry the operation.
----- amqrcsia.c : 1042 ------------------------------------------------------- 
08/02/2012 12:38:41 PM - Process(19161.269) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(...) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.1.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST2)

AMQ9999: Channel ''QM_TEST1.TO.QM_TEST2' to host '17.2.33.44' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION: The channel program running under process ID 19161 for
channel ''QM_TEST1.TO.QM_TEST2' ended abnormally. The host name is
'17.2.33.44'; in some cases the host name cannot be
determined and so is shown as '????'. ACTION: Look at previous error
messages for the channel program in the error logs to determine the
cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or
"SuppressMessage" attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini.
Further information can be found in the System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 887 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking these things up, I'd start first with the product manuals.  In this case, the Infocenter topic on channel states [says that](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/ic11230_.htm) a channel in PAUSED state is waiting on a retry interval.  The [sub-topic on channel errors](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/ic11270_.htm) explains why sending or receiving channels can be in retry:

> If a channel is unable to put a message to the target queue because
>   that queue is full or put inhibited, the channel can retry the
>   operation a number of times (specified in the message-retry count
>   attribute) at a time interval (specified in the message-retry interval
>   attribute). Alternatively, you can write your own message-retry exit
>   that determines which circumstances cause a retry, and the number of
>   attempts made. The channel goes to PAUSED state while waiting for the
>   message-retry interval to finish.

So if you stop your channels, you should see a message in the XMitQ on the sending side.  If you GET-enable that queue you can browse the message, look at the header and see which queue it is destined for.  On the receiving side, look to see if that queue is full.

Classic fast-sender, slow-consumer problem here.  If the consumer can't keep up, the messages back up on the receiving QMgr, then the channel goes to retry and they begin to back up on the sending QMgr.  Got to monitor depth and input handles on request queues.

Comment: Thank you, the target queue was full

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a DLQ is set.

Try reducing the message retry count to 1 to speed up use of the DLQ.